# Jetty-Runner doesn't take log config

Tags: java, logging, jetty

I'm running jetty-runner inside docker. I've tried putting jetty-logging.properties inside WEB-INF/classes, but it just seems to not pick it up. Has anyone ran into this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging initializes at the start of the JVM.

Using `WEB-INF/classes` is too late, as that's not available until way later, during the WebApp initialization.

If you are using Docker, the recommended approach is using the `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}` techniques. (as built into the official Jetty docker images)

Also, `jetty-runner` is deprecated and will be removed soon, it would be good for you to start transitioning off of it.